# C++ (Arduino) linked list, memory not freed when deleting a node inside the list

Tags: c++, list, memory, linked-list, arduino

I am developing a Client for an Arduino like plattform and I am trying to use a generic LinkedList library to organise objects. The list consists of the following defined nodes:

```
template<class T>
struct ListNode
{
    T data;
    ListNode<T> *next;
};
```

However, I ran into memory problems while using the linked list. I found out that the memory is not freed when deleting nodes inside the list but I cannot figure out why since the element is obviously removed from the list. In addition, the memory is always freed when deleting the last node of the list. I am using the following destroy method for deleting elements in the list:

```
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::destroy(int index){
    if(index < 0 || index >= _size)
        return;

    if(index == 0) {
        if (_size == 1) {
            delete root->data;
            delete root;
            root=NULL;
            last=NULL;
            _size=0;
            lastNodeGot = root;
            lastIndexGot = 0;
            isCached = false;
            return;
        } else {

            ListNode<T> *tmp = root->next;
            delete root->data;
            delete root;
            root = tmp;

            _size--;
            lastNodeGot = root;
            lastIndexGot = 0;
            isCached = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    ListNode<T> *tmp = getNode(index - 1);
    ListNode<T> *toDelete = getNode(index);
    tmp->next = toDelete->next;

    delete toDelete->data;
    delete toDelete;

    if (tmp->next == NULL) {
        last=tmp;
    }

    _size--;
    lastNodeGot = tmp;
    lastIndexGot = index-1;
    isCached = false;

    return;
}
```

If I delete all elements with the method above so that the list is empty, the memory is fully freed. However, the list is used in the client quite frequently with add/delete operations but it gets never emptied completely.

Btw. I am storing pointers to objects in the list like Strings.

Is there anything wrong with the code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `T* data;` in the Listnode struct? Or why are you doing `delete toDelete->data;` ?

Comment: I am storing pointer to objects that why I use the delete. Like this: `LinkedList<String*> test = LinkedList<String*>()`;

Comment: How do you check the data is not freed? Can you debug the code on your platform? What is not freed, the data member or the listnodes?

Also, for the `if (_size == 1)`-block it seems you might be able to use the `else `-block here as well?

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no way to debug the code line by line on the plattform. However I can print out the free memory (also sorted by heap and stack) through serial output. As said, a node is removed from the list but the amount of free memory does not increase. But deleting the last element works just fine (with freeing memory). (Btw. I am aware that this is not the minimal implementation, I only expanded it for debugging purposes)

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with deleting structs and the avr-gcc compiler but I have not found anything in the web yet.

Comment: Or maybe there is trouble measuring free memory. If i recall correctly there is no reliable way to do this, i think. The stack grows from one side of mem and the heap from the other side and there is not even a check built-in wether they collide.

Also, i don't know what you mean by "arduino-like platform", but if it were sth. like an arduino uno, then my advice were not to try that "clever" heap based linked lists and try to stick to arrays and fixed size char*'s if possible... otherwise your mem could fragment easily and the general overhead may spoil performance (i tried sth like this once)